# Integration involving rational function and exponentials

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, expectation

I hope I can find closed form solution for two following definite integrals. Unfortunately I don't have Mathematica and I can't find similar integrals in Tables. Can any one help me please?

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x^{1/2}+a x^{3/2}} dx
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \frac{xe^{-x}}{x^{1/2}(1+bx)^2} dx
\end{equation}

Comment: You can always use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Int+e%5E(-x)%2F(x%5E(1%2F2)%2Ba+x%5E(3%2F2))+for+x%3D0..Infinity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for the first integral
\begin{align}
\tag{a}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{x^{1/2}+ax^{3/2}} \mathrm{d}x &=
2\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{z\mathrm{e}^{-z^{2}}}{z+az^{3}} \mathrm{d}z \\
\tag{b}
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{a}} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-y^{2}/a} \frac{1}{1+y^{2}} \mathrm{d}y \\
\tag{c}
&= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a}} \mathrm{e}^{1/a} \mathrm{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\right)
\end{align}

Notes:

a. $x=z^{2}$

b. $y^{2}=az^{2}$

c. From [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.7.E1), we have the following integral definition of the complementary error function
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{erfc}(z) = \frac{2}{\pi} \mathrm{e}^{-z^{2}} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-z^{2}t^{2}}
\frac{1}{t^{2} + 1} \mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}

**Addendum**

For a proof of the above equation, see
[Show $\frac{2}{\pi} \mathrm{exp}(-z^{2}) \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{exp}(-z^{2}x^{2}) \frac{1}{x^{2}+1} \mathrm{d}x = \mathrm{erfc}(z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1973280/show-frac2-pi-mathrmexp-z2-int-0-infty-mathrmexp-z2x)

Answer (score 0):

The second integral is calculated in the same fashion:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{x e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x} (1+b x)^2} dx \underbrace{=}_{z=\sqrt{x}}\\
&&\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{z^2}{(1+b z^2)^2} 2 e^{-z^2} dz=\\
&&\int\limits_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{b} \frac{1}{1+b z^2} - \frac{1}{b} \frac{1}{1+b z^2)^2} \right) 2 e^{-z^2} dz=\\
&&\frac{2}{b^{3/2}} \left( \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\frac{z^2}{b}}}{1+z^2}dz - \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\frac{z^2}{b}}}{(1+z^2)^2}dz\right)=\\
&&\frac{2}{b^{3/2}} \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \exp(\frac{1}{b}) erfc(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}) - \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\frac{z^2}{b}}}{(1+z^2)^2}dz\right)=\\
&&\frac{2}{b^{3/2}} \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \exp(\frac{1}{b}) erfc(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}) - \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{1}{b} \left( \frac{z}{1+z^2} + \arctan(z)\right) z e^{-\frac{z^2}{b}} dz\right)=\\
&& \frac{\pi}{b^{3/2}}\exp(\frac{1}{b})erfc(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}) - \frac{2}{b^{5/2}} \int\limits_0^\infty \left( 1-\frac{1}{1+z^2} + z \arctan(z) \right) e^{-\frac{z^2}{b}} dz=\\
&&\frac{\pi}{b^{3/2}}\exp(\frac{1}{b})erfc(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}) - \frac{2}{b^{5/2}}\left( \sqrt{b} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2} \exp(\frac{1}{b}) erfc(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}) +   \int\limits_0^\infty   z e^{-\frac{z^2}{b}} \arctan(z)   dz \right)=\\
&&\frac{\pi}{b^{3/2}}\exp(\frac{1}{b})erfc(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}) - \frac{2}{b^{5/2}}\left( \sqrt{b} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2} \exp(\frac{1}{b}) erfc(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}) +  \frac{b}{2} \int\limits_0^\infty   e^{-\frac{z^2}{b}} \frac{1}{1+z^2}  dz \right)=\\
&&\frac{\pi}{b^{3/2}}\exp(\frac{1}{b})erfc(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}) - \frac{2}{b^{5/2}}\left( \sqrt{b} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2} \exp(\frac{1}{b}) erfc(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}) +  \frac{b}{2} \frac{\pi}{2} \exp(\frac{1}{b}) erfc(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}) \right)=\\
&& -\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{b^2} +  \frac{\pi}{2 b^{3/2}} \exp(\frac{1}{b}) erfc(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}) \left( 1+ \frac{2}{b} \right)
\end{eqnarray}