# How to integrate exponential $x^2$ with $1/x^2$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I am trying to calculate the integral for $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac { e^{-ax^2}}{x^2+\frac{1}{(2a)}}dx$$ I have no idea how to start on this and I have tried Wolfram alpha and similar sites ..the calculation time exceeds the usual time.

I am thinking of taking the derivation of exponential and integrate 1/() term but that would include logarithms and would make things more difficult and if I try to integrate exponential then I would have 1/()^2 term in next step which would again make it difficult ..I really don't know how to go on with this.

I think even a starting step on how to go about this would be a great help.

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1973280/show-frac2-pi-mathrmexp-z2-int-0-infty-mathrmexp-z2x?noredirect=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - ax^2 } }}{{x^2  + \frac{1}{{2a}}}}dx}  = \sqrt {2a} \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}t^2 } }}{{t^2  + 1}}dt}  = 2\sqrt {2a} \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}t^2 } }}{{t^2  + 1}}dt}  = \pi \sqrt {2a} e^{\frac{1}{2}} \operatorname{erfc}\left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}} \right)
$$
where $\operatorname{erfc}$ is the [complementary error function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.7.E1). Note that
$$
\pi \sqrt {2a} e^{\frac{1}{2}} \operatorname{erfc}\left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}} \right) = (2.324323459\ldots)\times \sqrt{a}.
$$

Comment: The last identity doesn‘t seem obvious to me. It is proven here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1973280/show-frac2-pi-mathrmexp-z2-int-0-infty-mathrmexp-z2x?noredirect=1

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I corrected the link, I just refer to the DLMF.

Comment: The first step : why are we writing all that equal to $\sqrt{2a}$ ?

Comment: @CuriouslyCurious I made the change of variables $t=\sqrt{2a}x$.